# SharePoint 2016: People Picker “Currently Unavailable” with Word 2016

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker

I made a column in sharepoint for people or groups.
Using quick parts i then added that into a word template for a content type.
when i click edit template eveything works great however if i then go to a make a document from content type template i get "currently Unavailable" where the people picker should be.

to make things more odd i then try to save document into library where it tells me in needs data in the people column and then the people picker works and it lets me save.

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Error is like the one here:
[Word 2013 Document Information Panel "Currently Unavailable" bug with SharePoint 2013](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94401/word-2013-document-information-panel-currently-unavailable-bug-with-sharepoint)